# И снова "скобки в скобках"

Tags: пунктуация

На днях возник вопрос, который заставил призадуматься. Редактировал один текст, там в одном из предложений скобки в скобках. Вспомнил, что и прежде уже не раз хотел выяснить (для себя лично), как же все-таки правильно оформлять подобные предложения. Обычно консультируюсь с сайтом gramota.ru, но они в последнее время отвечают лишь на "несложные" вопросы, судя по всему. Мой в очередной раз проигнорировали. Почитал здесь - знаю, что уже были подобные обсуждения: разные виды скобок и кавычек и т. д. Но... Вопрос в следующем: кто-то вообще может дать ссылку на официальный документ или монографию, в которых можно было бы прояснить, как правильно оформлять слово или группу слов, заключенные в скобки, которые, в свою очередь, находятся в части предложения, заключенного в скобки. Или этого в принципе делать нельзя. Я лично не нашел ни у Розенталя, ни в других источниках... Спасибо.

Comment: Послушайте, ну при чем тут *официальный* документ? Официальные документы - это распоряжения правительства, местной власти и т.п с подписями и печатями. А правописание не подчиняется официальным органам (за исключением топонимики)...

Comment: Вода, друг мой, просто вода... В болтовне на кухне мы и в самом деле можем говорить что и как угодно. Но нормы языка официально регламентируются, если вы этого не знали... К примеру, есть случаи, когда у слова два варианта ударения. Но, например, для дикторов на ТВ существуют однозначные правила, как произносить это слово. С правилами правописания, безусловно, не так все фатально, но и тут хотелось бы писать правильно, чтобы не прослыть неграмотным писакой... А раздолбайства у нас и так предостаточно. Но все равно спасибо. ))

Answer (score 4):

Таких правил нет и быть не может, вся пунктуация регулируется соображениями целесообразности. Если здесь необходимо поставить двое скобок и заменить их ничем нельзя, значит, ставим двое. Есть примечание в Правилах 1956 года о встрече внутренних и внешних скобок:

Примечание. При встрече в конце предложения внутренних и внешних скобок допускается, в случае необходимости, употребление скобок различного рисунка (круглых и квадратных).

По-моему, само наличие этого примечания уже говорит о корректности употребления двух скобок. Другое дело, что смотрится это некрасиво, поэтому нужно попытаться перестроить предложение и убрать вторые скобки, но если этого сделать нельзя - ничего не поделаешь, ставим двое.

Comment: Спасибо. )) Подобную логическую цепочку и я соорудил. Подумал, что должны быть и какие-то правила (типа "жи и ши пиши с буквой "и"), просто я их не нашел... Ладно, оставлю для себя гештальт незавершенным пока.